# asp.net routing syntax with no action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to establish a route where there is no action but just a parameter:

> domain.com (without any parameter, should go to one controller)

however,

> domain.com/somestring
>
> domain.com/anotherstring
>
> domain.com/anythingreally

should go to another controller (and pass the string as a parameter).

I can't figure out the syntax since, from what I understand, ASP is using the parameter to figure out the action but I want any and all strings to go to the same action.

---

These are my routes:

```
Application.UseMvc(Routes =>
{
    Routes.MapRoute(name: "go",         template: "{controller=Go}/{action=Go}/{id?}");
    Routes.MapRoute(name: "redirect",   template: "{controller=Redirect}/{id?}");
    Routes.MapRoute(name: "default",    template: "{controller=Short}/{action=Index}");
 });
```

what I want to achieve is:

> domain.com goes to Short/Index
>
> domain.com/go/somestring goes to go/go and gets somestring as parameter
>
> domain.com/somestring goes to redirect/index and gets somestring as parameter

The controllers are simple:

The go controller is defined as:

```
public class GoController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Go(string Id)
```

the redirect controller is defined at:

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(string Id)
```

and the short controller as:

```
public class ShortController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(RegisterViewModel Data)
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code and your routing code? How are you targeting your controller?

Comment: I just added the code to the post for clarification

Comment: {controller} is where Go, Default, or Redirect will go but only if your controllers name is GoController, RedirectController, etc. I don't believe `{controller=Go}/{action=Go}/{id?}` is valid. If the controller is Go then it will route to the action. If you don't want to use an action then remove it. id should be the name of the parameter in the method. So `Public Function GetGo(byval id as string) as IActionResult` in `GoController` would match assuming the request method was a Get.

Comment: The route `/{controller}/{id}` would work for your method assuming Go was selected in the uri and your controller method accepted your request method.

Comment: {controller=Go}/{action=Go}/{id?} works properly, in fact it's the only thing that works. The real question is how do I route 'anything' after the domain name to a single controller, UNLESS it's 'go' or if there is nothing after the domain name.

Comment: That's good. domainname.com/Go or domainname.com/Redirect, etc.. Your controller is GoController, RedirectController, or DefaultController. Now your method with the matching parameter {id} will have to be available in those controllers.

Comment: I've had similar case and just removing `{action}` on route config to do that, and you also need to ensure only one action method allowed on those controller to avoid ambiguation.

Comment: how do you recover the parameter passed in the path in this case? domain.com/parameter and also what will be called in the controller?

Comment: I did more tests: with Routes.MapRoute(name: "redirect", template: "{controller=Redirect}/{action}"); and Routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Short}/{action=Index}"); the default route works well, so domain.com goes to short controller; but when I type domain.com/something it doesn't go to the redirect controller

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I shouldn't route everything to a single controller, analyze the url and then do the dispatch manually :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your routes should be like this

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "redirect",
         template: "{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "go",
          template: "go/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Go", action = "Go" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Short}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


    });
```

in template you have to set the what `URL` you want and remember the sequence matters. You should also check this [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the order matters!!  Thanks for this.  The ordering was my issue.  I didn't think it would matter in compiled code, but hey, easy enough fix.