# how to achieve classic webapi 2 routing in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm porting an application from asp.net webapi 2 to asp.net core and I've discovered an issue with routing that I can't seem to figure out.

I have a WebApi 2 controller like this:

```
namespace Sopost.Controllers
{
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;

    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Verify(string id)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

The route mapping is as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

With this controller I'm able to test the resource with both of these urls

> http://localhost/api/Test/Verify?id=tokenString
>   http://localhost/api/Test/tokenstring

In an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application I use the following:

```
namespace Sopost.Controllers
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public IActionResult Verify(string id)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

With this mapping:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I can successfully test the action with this URL

> http://localhost/Test/verify?id=tokenstring

However, the following URL produces a 404 error:

> http://localhost/Test/tokenstring

If i use attribute routing to explicitly fix the routing for the broken url, then the other url breaks.

**EDIT**
I found a work around here [asp.net routing syntax with no action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443582/asp-net-routing-syntax-with-no-action)
 and now my startup.cs looks like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "testroute",
        template: "test/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Verify" });

});
```

This will allow me to test with both urls, however, I have to add a route like this for every controller.

Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working the way that it worked in WebApi 2? Also, any pointers on how I can get both urls to work in asp.net core without adding a global route for every controller?  Since I'm porting this application, I'm not 100% sure on how clients are calling our api so I would like both to work for backwards compatibility if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve same behaviour using attributes

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [HttpGet("verify")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public IActionResult Verify(string id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This way both requests will work well and you don't need to write `routes.MapRoute` for each controller